# Android Lint: Unused Resource Warning Not Going Away

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, resources, android-lint

I'm getting a warning in my android xml

```
The resource R.string.goals_header_time appears to be unused
The resource R.string.goals_header_units appears to be unused
The resource R.string.goals_header_current appears to be unused
The resource R.string.measurement appears to be unused
The resource R.string.goals_header_name appears to be unused
The resource R.string.goal_name appears to be unused
The resource R.string.goals_header_goal appears to be unused
```

Once I get rid of those strings the warning is still there.

Cleaning the project and restarting eclipse doesn't fix it either.  The only way I've been able to get rid of the warnings so far is to go into the preferences, turn off checking for unused resources and then turning it back on again.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured it out.  To rerun lint right click on the project go to android tools->run lint

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go. Even the refresh button at the right won't parse your code again.
There should also be a checkbox button in the menu bar, that's a shortcut for "project/android tools/run lint".

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this specifically with Android Lint warnings, but occasionally Eclipse will come up with errors that just won't go away on their own. You can right click them (or select many then right click) and then delete them.

Comment: I can right click to the very right of the first line of the xml and clear the lint warnings, but then the warnings that should be there don't appear.  Thanks though